# customary loss function in tf.model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I want to implement a model with a custom loss function using keras.

I will simulate by sampling a dataset according to the following function:

```
def sampler(N1, N2, N3):
    np.random.seed(42)
    # Sampler #1: PDE domain
    t1 = np.random.uniform(low=T0,
                           high=T,
                           size=[N1,1])
    s1 = np.random.uniform(low=S1,
                           high=S2,
                           size=[N1,1])

    # Sampler #2: boundary condition
    t2 = np.random.uniform(low=T0,
                           high=T,
                           size=[N2,1])
    s2 = np.zeros(shape=(N2, 1))
    
    # Sampler #3: initial/terminal condition
    t3 = T * np.ones((N3,1)) #Terminal condition
    s3 = np.random.uniform(low=S1,
                           high=S2,
                           size=[N3,1])
    
    return (t1, s1, t2, s2, t3, s3)
```

Each subset `(t1, s1)`, `(t2, s2)` and `(t3, s3)` should be evaluated by a unique term in the loss function:

```
def loss(model, t1, x1, t2, x2, t3, x3):
    # Loss term #1: PDE
    V = model(t1, x1)
    V_t = tf.gradients(V, t1)[0]
    V_x = tf.gradients(V, x1)[0]
    V_xx = tf.gradients(V_x, x1)[0]
    f = V_t + r*x1*V_x + 0.5*sigma**2*x1**2*V_xx - r*V 

    L1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(f))

    #Loss term #2: boundary condition
    L2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(model(t2, x2) - 0)) 
    
    # Loss term #3: initial/terminal condition
    L3 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(model(t3, x3) - tf.math.maximum(x3-K,0)))
```

I have established the following parameters:

```
# Set random seeds
np.random.seed(123)
tf.random.set_seed(123)

# Strike price

K = 0.5

# PDE parameters
r = 0.02            # Interest rate
sigma = 0.18        # Volatility

# Time limits
T0 = 0.0 + 1e-10    # Initial time
T  = 1.0            # Terminal time

# Space limits
S1 = 0.0 + 1e-10    # Low boundary
S2 = 1.0            # High boundary

# Number of samples
NS_1 = 1000
NS_2 = 100
NS_3 = 100
```

The Model

```
class DGM(tf.keras.Model):
    
    def __init__(self, n_layers, n_nodes, dimensions=1):
        """
        Parameters:
            - n_layers:     number of layers
            - n_nodes:      number of nodes in (inner) layers
            - dimensions:   number of spacial dimensions
        """
        super().__init__()
        
        self.n_layers = n_layers

        self.initial_layer = DenseLayer(dimensions + 1, n_nodes, activation="relu")
        self.lstmlikelist = []
        for _ in range(self.n_layers):
            self.lstmlikelist.append(LSTMLikeLayer(dimensions + 1, n_nodes, activation="relu"))
        self.final_layer = DenseLayer(n_nodes, 1, activation=None)


    def call(self, t, x):
        X = tf.concat([t,x], 1)

        S = self.initial_layer.call(X)
        for i in range(self.n_layers):
            S = self.lstmlikelist[i].call({'S': S, 'X': X})
        result = self.final_layer.call(S)

        return result
    


# Neural network layers

class DenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
        

  def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_outputs, activation):
      """
      Parameters:
      - n_inputs:     number of inputs
      - n_outputs:    number of outputs
      - activation:   activation function
      """
      super(DenseLayer, self).__init__()
      self.n_inputs = n_inputs
      self.n_outputs = n_outputs
      self.W = self.add_weight(shape=(self.n_inputs, self.n_outputs),
                               initializer='random_normal',
                               trainable=True)
      self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(1, self.n_outputs),
                               initializer='random_normal',
                               trainable=True)
      self.activation = _get_function(activation)
      
  def call(self, inputs):
        S = tf.add(tf.matmul(inputs, self.W), self.b)
        S = self.activation(S)

        return S



class LSTMLikeLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_outputs, activation):
        """
        Parameters:
            - n_inputs:     number of inputs
            - n_outputs:    number of outputs
            - activation:   activation function
        """
      
        super(LSTMLikeLayer, self).__init__()

        self.n_outputs = n_outputs
        self.n_inputs = n_inputs


        
        
        self.Uz = self.add_weight("Uz", shape=[self.n_inputs, self.n_outputs])
        self.Ug = self.add_weight("Ug", shape=[self.n_inputs, self.n_outputs])
        self.Ur = self.add_weight("Ur", shape=[self.n_inputs, self.n_outputs])
        self.Uh = self.add_weight("Uh", shape=[self.n_inputs, self.n_outputs])
        self.Wz = self.add_weight("Wz", shape=[self.n_outputs, self.n_outputs])
        self.Wg = self.add_weight("Wg", shape=[self.n_outputs, self.n_outputs])
        self.Wr = self.add_weight("Wr", shape=[self.n_outputs, self.n_outputs])
        self.Wh = self.add_weight("Wh", shape=[self.n_outputs, self.n_outputs])
        self.bz = self.add_weight("bz", shape=[1, self.n_outputs])
        self.bg = self.add_weight("bg", shape=[1, self.n_outputs])
        self.br = self.add_weight("br", shape=[1, self.n_outputs])
        self.bh = self.add_weight("bh", shape=[1, self.n_outputs])
        

        self.activation = _get_function(activation)


    
    def call(self, inputs):
        S = inputs['S']
        X = inputs['X']

        Z = self.activation(tf.add(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, self.Uz), tf.matmul(S, self.Wz)), self.bz))
        G = self.activation(tf.add(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, self.Ug), tf.matmul(S, self.Wg)), self.bg))
        R = self.activation(tf.add(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, self.Ur), tf.matmul(S, self.Wr)), self.br))
        H = self.activation(tf.add(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, self.Uh), tf.matmul(tf.multiply(S, R), self.Wh)), self.bh))
        Snew = tf.add(tf.multiply(tf.subtract(tf.ones_like(G), G), H), tf.multiply(Z, S))

        return Snew



def _get_function(name):
    f = None
    if name == "tanh":
        f = tf.nn.tanh
    elif name == "sigmoid":
        f = tf.nn.sigmoid
    elif name == "relu":
        f = tf.nn.relu
    elif not name:
        f = tf.identity
    
    assert f is not None
    
    return f
```

This would be my approach for an exemplary model:

```
model = DGM(n_layers=2, n_nodes = 3)
model.compile(
    optimizer = "Adam", loss = loss
)
model.fit()
```

Error trace back:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-12-f781fe65eb00> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit()

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1030     version_utils.disallow_legacy_graph('Model', 'fit')
   1031     self._assert_compile_was_called()
-> 1032     self._check_call_args('fit')
   1033     _disallow_inside_tf_function('fit')
   1034 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _check_call_args(self, method_name)
   2468           'Models passed to `' + method_name + '` can only have `training` '
   2469           'and the first argument in `call` as positional arguments, '
-> 2470           'found: ' + str(extra_args) + '.')
   2471 
   2472   def _validate_compile(self, optimizer, metrics, **kwargs):

ValueError: Models passed to `fit` can only have `training` and the first argument in `call` as positional arguments, found: ['x'].
```

Now how can I fit the model in accordance with the customary loss function I have set up?

Comment: It seems you are using Model subclassing. You can use model.fit() or write your own custom training loop. Do you get any errors while using model.fit()?

Comment: Yes, exactly!
If I just add model.fit() without any arguments I get the following mistake:
```ValueError: Models passed to `fit` can only have `training` and the first argument in `call` as positional arguments, found: ['x'].```
I don't exactly understand how I'm supposed to feed in the different samples to evaluate them for the different terms of the loss function.

Comment: Can you update your question so that it includes the `fit()` command and the complete traceback of error?

Comment: off course! done

Comment: You are not passing any data for training to happen. You have to use `model.fit(x = 'your training data', y = 'your labels', epochs = 'number of epochs')`. For reference check this [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

Comment: How do I pass in the training data? Is it as simple as ```model.fit(x = [t1, s1, t2, s2, t3, s3], epochs = 1000)```. 
There are no 'labels' to pass in since the loss function evaluates whether the three conditions are met for each of the three input sets  ```(t1, s1)```,``` (t2, s2)``` and ```(t3, s3) ```